# How to convert these codes into JsonObject?

Tags: android, json

```
{
"id":1465271593,
"title":"SmartChairIoT",
"private":"true",
"feed":"https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/1465271593.json",
"status":"frozen",
"updated":"2016-09-26T13:45:42.461310Z",
"created":"2015-08-11T03:51:06.988349Z",
"creator":"https://personal.xively.com/users/1302767g",
"version":"1.0.0",
"datastreams":
[{"id":"force1","current_value":"0",
"at":"2016-09-26T13:45:36.212846Z",
"max_value":"1023.0",
"min_value":"0.0"},
"product_id":"KsihJuMSx165179ihiIC",
"device_serial":"GNGZNY2TT44Y"
}
```

Comment: your json is invaid..please put right json with correct format

Comment: this is the data i get from the cloud. So now what i want is convert this data into JsonObject but i do not know how to convert into the correct format

Comment: you need to check the data in here http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 0):

you should try using a library such as gson
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Leveraging-the-Gson-Library

Answer (score 0):

This is the valid JSON. The array was not closed in your code.

```
{
    "id": 1465271593,
    "title": "SmartChairIoT",
    "private": "true",
    "feed": "https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/1465271593.json",
    "status": "frozen",
    "updated": "2016-09-26T13:45:42.461310Z",
    "created": "2015-08-11T03:51:06.988349Z",
    "creator": "https://personal.xively.com/users/1302767g",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "datastreams": [{
        "id": "force1",
        "current_value": "0",
        "at": "2016-09-26T13:45:36.212846Z",
        "max_value": "1023.0",
        "min_value": "0.0"
    }],
    "product_id": "KsihJuMSx165179ihiIC",
    "device_serial": "GNGZNY2TT44Y"
}
```

You can convert it to JSON object by

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("Your JSON Data");
```